# My Site Links go to incorrrect domain

Tags: development, user-profile

I have a my sites host site collection (http://insitedev/site/my) but when I click on some of the links they go to the machinename instead of the host name I have set up. This can be seen in the video below:

http://screencast.com/t/lKIKhJmg

Can anyone please help

Answer (score 1):

Check out the setting for the My Site Host in Central Admin > Application Management > Manage Service Application > User Profile Service > Setup My Sites under My Site Settings.

HTH